# Swiper doesn't show Image (from URI) until scrolling

Tags: react-native

I have a Swiper with one Image-children (the same problem when I have multiple images as children). If I navigate to this screen I except to see the image.

But: The swiper area is black (invisible) until I scroll down a little bit. If I scroll, the image get loaded.

```
<Swiper height={300} >
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}><Image style={{ flex: 1 }} source={{uri: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx'}} /></View>
</Swiper>
```

I am using the iOS Simulator with the following versions:

react-native-swiper v1.5.13

react-native v0.46.4

Comment: have you try to cover the swiper inside a view compenent with flex:1 ?

Comment: Can you provide full scene component with styles? I tried to replicate the issue and the image **a)** showed up ok when I specified static height and width for `<Image style={{width:260,height:66}} ...` but **b)** didn't show up at all with flex: 1 in its style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `removeClippedSubviews={false}` to the `Swiper` solved the problem.